# How to view data map of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, schema

I am trying to find a way to view the data map of my companies in a local SQL Server database. Something that looks like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Mediawiki_database_Schema.svg.

I can connect to the server in Crystal Reports via ODBC connection. Is there a way to do this in Crystal Reports, or do I need to use another program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has (very) basic diagram functionality.  From Management Studio within each database you should see a container that looks like this:

[image]

Simply right click -> new database diagram and you're on your way.

Other programs with the capability of reverse engineering the database include Visio Professional and ERWin ($$$).

You can draw your own with a tool like this: https://drive.draw.io/

Comment: Thanks! I fond database diagrams, but now I get this error

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
------------------------------

A member of the db_owner role must use the database diagramming functionality in order to setup the required database diagramming objects on the SQL Server.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: So you're missing the necessary permissions. If you are not in a position to be added to the db_owner role, you could try to get a copy of the database schema to a location where you can have the elevated permissions.  Otherwise, you're back to using one of the tools I suggested (or others ... there are many ER diagramming tools out there).